# Excel Interop Sorting

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have an c# project which automates excel using the excel interop. One issue that I am running into is sorting using the excel filters, when I protect the sheet using C#, I am disabling sorting, when I unprotect it I am able to use the filters in the ListObject to sort. Given that I need to protect the sheet is their a C# event that can tell me when a user selected the header of the list Object column and select Sort A to Z or Largest to smallest
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get anything in C# that isn't available via the Excel object model. If such an event exists, it would probably have some form of it on the `Application` object (the `Application` object has events like `SheetBeforeDoubleClick` that are duplicates of the events that happen on the individual books/sheets like the `BeforeDoubleClick` event of the `Worksheet` object).

The `SheetTableUpdate` event may help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application_events.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of outdated and you mention no Excel version but from what I gather, I think this may be able to help you.

[Sort Excel table (ListObject) on protected sheet using Excel Interop c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371199/sort-excel-table-listobject-on-protected-sheet-using-excel-interop-c-sharp/40371200#40371200)